# Edit metatada of an app that is “Pending Developer Release” without resubmitting?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an updated to an existing app that has been approved, and is currently “Pending Developer Release”. I realized that I want to change the app’s description before I release it. I can click the Edit button on that version’s metadata, and type in a new description. What will happen if I click “Save”? Will it just work, or will it need to be re-approved? I haven’t found anything in the developer documentation that exactly addresses this problem. The closest I can find is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW5), but it doesn’t cover exactly this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may safely make changes to the app description. Once the app has been approved, the description may be changed freely, as many times as the developer wants.
You may see this in apps that e.g. change their price for one day and state so in their description. They could not possibly send an update to Apple, change the price, the submit another update and then change the price again... All in 24/48 hours!
You cannot change other things such as keywords or screenshots without a new update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document that describes the various states in which you can edit:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

According to the document, you cannot edit when you are "Pending Developer Release"

We had this happen last week when we released our very first iPad version and didnt add iPad screenshots to the App description.

We "bit the bullet" and released the app without the proper screenshots and then quickly uploaded a new binary with updated screenshots.

Only took Apple 5 days to review so our new iPad was released to current customers without iPad screenshots but we go them up updated and then got the app description squared away 5 days later.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't let you to modify your app description and app screenshots after it has been approved, because of the "empty" apps, which were paid apps but no contents ( description wasn't same as the app knowledge ). So I think if you click Save, won't happen anything ( it won't update, but I never tried !!! ). I think if you don't have really important modifications in your description, you could release your app, and you can create a new version. My experience is the new apps have longer review time, than the updates.